# how to set default parameters to function in better way

Tags: javascript, node.js

For testing purposes, I wrote a function that generates user objects. The function has parameters with default values, but we can customize it if necessary. User objects may grow large, f.e. these can have 30 properties each, and I don't want to update function parameters every time plus it looks messy.

Maybe there is better way to do it?

```
const defaultUser ={
  id: 'test_id',
  last_time: '17:59:00',
  slide_id: 'slide ID',
  name: 'AA1',
  address: 'blabala',
  number_of_houses: 500,
  age: 20,
  active: false,
  children: {
    boy: [],
    girl: []
  },
} 
const generateUSer = ({id:defaultUser.id, last_time=defualtUser.last_time, .....and all the props }={})=>{
return{
id,
last_time,
... and all the props
}
}


const user = generateUSer();
cosnt second_user = generateUSer({name:'test_2'})
```

Comment: Have you ever read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_parameters? You're kind of complicating things with the way you attempt to declare default values -- `function generateUser({ id = uuid(), ...rest } = {}) { ... }` would probably suffice indeed. In fact, I am not even sure your snippet is valid ECMAScript (for Node.js), although I am surprised `const f = () => { x: 1 }` is accepted by by Node 16, even though I can't tell what the statement means, exactly.

Comment: @Teemu tnx i fixed that

Comment: @ArmenMichaeli i fixed that

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
function generateUser(options={}) {
    return {...defaultUser, ...options}
}
```

This will make a copy of `defaultUser` and extend it with your options.

Comment: If I have a nested object with 3 props and I want to override only one prop, this is not good, all the props are deleted.

Comment: @aviv.L: in this case, you need something like lodash merge() to combine nested objects recursively

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove `id` generation from your `defaultUser` inside the `generateUser()` cause it will be cleaner to understand that each user have unique id. Overall, I can suggest improving you `generateUser()` this way:

```
const generateUser = (customProps = {}) => {
  const id = customProps.id || uuid();
  return { ...defaultUser, ...customProps, id };
};
```

Spread operator will do the job of annoying reprint of each property and increase the code readability. If you're not interested in unique ids, just ignore the step with id.